# Value in hidden field repeating with comma

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a hidden field inside a gridview and the values are bound to the gridview.

Let us assume the value of hidden field is 1.

when I tried to retrieve data from it in code behind, the value of hidden field is changed to "1,1".

Comment: Are you using an `UpdatePanel` or jQuery?

Comment: Can you create a small example where this happens and post this code where the item is populated and where the item is read. Ensure it contains the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue? This is needed so you can isolate other code from the issue.

Comment: you have the hidden value with the same id/name many times, so its return all the times is found on html page

Answer (score 4):

When for some reason you post-back with many elements with the same id/name, then the value you get server-side for that id/name is a comma separated list of the values from the duplicated elements.

For example you post this 3 hidden input elements, with the same name

```
<input type="hidden" name="par" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="par" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="par" value="1">
```

you get this on code behind `par="1,1,1"`

Answer (score 0):

Use asp.net HiddeField controls, this way you will make sure each hiddenfield will have a unique client id.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="MyLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisibleValue") %>'/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("HiddenValue")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the code behind you might access the hiddenfield values with something like this:

```
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView.Rows
    Dim Value as string= CType(gvRow.FindControl("MyHiddenField"), HiddenField).Value
Next
```